# SQL Server stored procedure generates results but doesn't return them

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[DynamicDropDownList]
(
    @TableName varchar(100),
    @DataTextField varchar(100),
    @ValueTextField varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

declare @results table (DataTextField varchar(255), DataValueFIeld varchar(2));
    declare @sql varchar(max);

    set @sql = ('select ' + @DataTextField + ', ' + @ValueTextField +
                ' from ' + @TableName +
                ' order by ' + @DataTextField);

    exec(@sql);

    return;
END
```

When I run it in LinqPad, I get this output:

[image: output]

Code that is returning "results 0":

```
var results = db.DynamicDropDownList("Countries", "Country", "CountryCode");
```

In my web project, I'm never able to access the result set - it just says nothing was returned. What am I doing wrong that is preventing the result set from being returned?

Comment: Show us the code from your web project that runs the sproc.

Comment: The .NET code that's supposed to retrieve the result set would be relevant

Comment: I updated the OP to include the requested code. The sproc is being accessed from a .dbml file.

Comment: Where is the code from your web project?

Comment: All your parameter datatypes would be better as `sysname` and you should use the `QUOTENAME` function when concatenating them into the string and `nvarchar(max)` not `varchar(max)`. Are you testing in Linqpad under the same account as your application uses? Ownership chaining doesn't apply to dynamic SQL. maybe you are getting and burying a permissions error.

Comment: I didn't mean to be misleading by posting the LinqPad image, it just had a nicer output display than SQL management studio. SQL management studio returns the same thing, 2 panes, one with the results set and one with a "Return Value" column with 1 row containing the value "0". Nothing is erroring or anything like that. The code is being executed but not returned correctly.

Comment: Have you tried removing the "return;" statement?  Also, In case you didn't realize it, this is some extroardinarily dangerous code in your SP. There are ample opportunities for SQL injection. With this syntax, you have lost nearly all benefits of using a SP. I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Removing 'return' makes no difference. I know it's dangerous but it's not publicly accessible.

Comment: The problem must be in your c# code.  What type is "db" in your code "var results = db.DynamicDropDownList..."?  Maybe Linq2Sql or EF4 or home-made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exec() command makes it difficult for Linq2Sql to determine the shape of the output.  Namely, the column names could change every time you run your SP.

The workaround is to add a partial class to your project that defines a method which will invoke the SPROC and return the result set as an IMultipleResult object. You will need to create one ResultType for each possible output.

This article by Scott Guthrie talks about it more:  (in the section "Handling Multiple Result Shapes") http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Of course, it would be WAY simpler if you changed your stored proc to have consistent column names in the result set.  Like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DynamicDropDownList]
(
    @TableName varchar(100),
    @DataTextField varchar(100),
    @ValueTextField varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    declare @results table (DataTextField varchar(255), DataValueFIeld varchar(2));
    declare @sql varchar(max);

    set @sql = ('select ' + @DataTextField + ' AS Data, ' + @ValueTextField + ' AS Value ' +
                ' from ' + @TableName + ' AS LookupTable ' +
                ' order by ' + @DataTextField);

    exec(@sql);

    return;
END
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer because of the column names you added, but the root cause of the issue was that when I initially added the sproc to my dbml, the return type was set as "Unknown" (I think because I initially didn't have column names declared). When I made changes to the sproc and deleted/readded it to my dbml, the return type never updated. Only when I deleted it, built, closed Visual Studio, reopened VS, and then readded it, did it set the return type to "Auto generated". I did try code similar to yours before I posted here, but it was just never being updated in the dbml.